# System.Data.Sqlite - Failure to install Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite, visual-studio-2015, system.data.sqlite

I am trying to install the design-time components of System.Data.Sqlite -- I want to be able to connect to SQLite databases from within Visual Studio, execute queries, and retrieve data.

As per the instructions on the [System.Data.Sqlite downloads page](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki), I downloaded the setup bundle for 32-bit Windows, targeting .NET 4.6.

When I try to install, I get the following error:

> Failed to install Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime: vcredist_x86_2015_VSU2.exe, Another version of this product is already installed. Installation of this version cannot continue. To configure or remove the existing version of this product, use Add/Remove Programs on the Control Panel

I am running Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition Update 3, with cumulative hotfixes, available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt752379.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396); on Windows 10 64-bit.
I tried uninstalling the **Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x86)** and rerunning the VS 2015 Community Edition hotfix installer to reinstall it, and then rerunning the SQLite installer, but the same error still occurred.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were oh-so-close to the solution. You've just got a couple steps backwards.

The issue is that the System.Data.Sqlite package includes VC++ Update 2, but you've already got the newer Update 3 installed. Rather than recognize there's already a newer version installed, all the setup program sees is that installing U2 failed and bails out. So, we need to let it do its thing and install the U2 package to get past that point:

1. Uninstall "Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x86) - 14.0.24212"
2. Install the Sqlite package
3. THEN re-install Update 3

Comment: It took me about 2 hours to reinstall Update 3, but all's well that ends well.

Comment: why they don't offer an installer without the VCRT setup is beyond me...